# Wordpress select custom post by metabox

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I have a custom post called event, but I need  to query only those posts which have a custom metabox(is a checkbox) called `Show On The Homepage: and only if that checkbox is checked.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Event','posts_per_page' => 1000 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

My question is there a way to query this, or I will have to do a `get_meta` in the loop and check each one with an if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer this anyway

Your answer is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

So use `meta_key` and `meta_value` in your args